# Batch file to copy the most recently modified files within a directory to another

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy the most recently modified files within a directory to another directory using a batch file.

I am able to copy the most recently modified file, but I want to copy multiple files.

```bash
@echo off
set source="D:\source"
set target="D:\target"

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.* /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END
:END
TIMEOUT 4
```

Is there a way to set the number of files while copying?

Comment: Yes there is. Use an incrementing counter, (with the `set` command), or alternatively use the line numbering capabilities of `find.exe` or `findstr.exe`. Both methods have been used extensively throughout this site's pages; please use the search facility, at the top of the page, to locate and adapt one, or more, of them.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to copy a specific number of files by introducing a counter variable and a loop, check this out :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "source=D:\source"
set "target=D:\target"
set count=0
set maxCount=5

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR "%source%\*" /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO (
    COPY "%source%\%%I" "%target%\"
    echo Copied: %%I
    set /a count+=1
    IF !count! EQU !maxCount! GOTO :END
)

:END
TIMEOUT 4
```

Comment: There is a glaringly obvious omission from your code.

Comment: You're using delayed expansion but you haven't enabled it.